# Handler post is not working in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, runnable

Could someone show me what is wrong?

I try to use a `Handler` post a `Runnable` but it's not execute

```
var mHandler: Handler? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mHandler = Handler()
    var runnable = Runnable {
        Log.d("TEST", "++++ runable")
        Log.d("TEST", "++++ come end")
    }
    Log.d("TEST", "++++ runnable" + runnable)
    Log.d("TEST", "++++ handle" + mHandler)
    mHandler!!.post { runnable }
}
```

This is output

> 09-21 00:56:04.067 4419-4419/? D/TEST: ++++
>   runnablecom.vpioneer.activity.MainActivity$onCreate$runnable$1@529b8fb4
>   09-21 00:56:04.067 4419-4419/? D/TEST: ++++ handleHandler
>   (android.os.Handler) {529b8cb4}

Comment: I would recommend changing your first line to `lateinit var mHandler: Handler` since you are creating it `onCreate`. Then you don't need to worry about the nullability concerns.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First at all, don't use `!!` operator, it is a very bad practice (from the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator)). With `?` you will reach the same behaviour but checking if the instance became null before executing it.

Saying this, using:

```
mHandler?.post { runnable }
```

You are actually creating a new lambda containing runnable line. see here below in a more readable way:

```
mHandler?.post { 
   runnable 
}
```

This is the equivalent in Java:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        runnable;
    }
});
```

To solve this:

**Option 1:** getting rid of the runnable declaration

```
mHandler?.post { /*the content of your runnable*/ }
```

**Option 2:** using your runnable instance

```
mHandler?.post(runnable) // normal parentheses
```

**Option 3:** crazy way

```
mHandler?.post { runnable.run() }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, My big mistake

Comment: I made the same mistake. Thank you sir for pointing that out.

Comment: !! is not necessarily bad practice if something absolutely shouldn't be null. Otherwise problem might be masked. On the other hand ?. will suffice and be preferred for most situations.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, I hope this is working

```
   Handler().postDelayed({
            // You code and delay time
   }, 1000L)
```

Comment: Thx @NajibAhmedPuthawala , Upvoted for saving my day

Answer (score 1):

You are not starting `runnbale`. Try this:

```
mHandler!!.post { runnable.run() }
```

This is also valid:

```
mHandler!!.post { 
    Log.d("TEST", "++++ runable")
    Log.d("TEST", "++++ come end")
}
```

Comment: I get an error: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**